# absolute structure VS complete sentence after em dash

Tags: absolute-construction, em-dash

> Primarily, the banker-customer relationship is that of debtor and creditor--who is which **depending** on whether the customer's account is in credit or is overdrawn.

I am aware that a complete sentence can be used after em dash, but here is a absolute structure used. I am wondering are there any differences between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence as quoted looks inconsistent because the first pair of nouns is in the singular (banker/customer) while the second one is in the plural (debtors/creditors). Surfing the Internet, I've found that the original text presents both pairs of nouns in the singular form:

> When anyone opens a current account at a bank, he is lending the bank
> money, repayment of which he may demand at any time, either in cash or
> by drawing a cheque in favour of another person. Primarily, **the
> banker-customer relationship is that of debtor and creditor — who is
> which depending on whether the customer’s account is in credit or is
> overdrawn**. But, in addition to that basically simple concept, the
> bank and its customer owe a large number of obligations to one
> another. Many of these obligations can give rise to problems and
> complications but a bank customer, unlike, say, a buyer of goods,
> cannot complain that the law is loaded against him." (GORDON BARRIE
> and AUBREY L. DLAMOND The Consumer Society and the Law)

What appears after the em dash does not sound like good English. As OP says, there should be a tensed verb:

- Primarily, the banker-customer relationship is that of debtor and creditor — who is which **will depend** on whether the customer’s account is in credit or is overdrawn.

For the V-ing to work with an absolute construction, there should be a comma and the subject should be different, for example:

- Primarily, the banker-customer relationship is that of debtor and creditor, the person being one or the other **depending** on whether the customer’s account is in credit or is overdrawn.

In the revision above, the subject of the absolute clause can be "the person" and the non-finite "being", with "depending" being more like a preposition. In this respect, we can read on page 127 of *The American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style*:

> Some participles, such as *concerning, considering, failing,* and *granting*, function
> as prepositions and can be used to introduce a sentence without causing a dangling
> modifier. A few participial phrases, such as *speaking of* and *judging by*, also work this
> way:
>
> *Concerning the proposal, there was little debate among the board members.*
>
> *Considering his reputation for honesty, his arrest came as a shock.*
>
> *Speaking of exceptional performances, did you see her latest movie?*
>
> *Judging by the applause, the play was a success.*

Another possible parsing consists of considering "the person being one or the other" as the subject, in which case "depending" is the non-finite verb of the absolute clause.

Comment: I'm wondering why the absolute structure can't be as it is.

Comment: I simply don't think a clause makes a good subject for an absolute construction.

Answer (score 0):

The example sentence reads fine to me.

The dash is effectively acting like a comma, it's just more direct and forceful - immediately providing clarification or additional information, or driving home an important point. (<- that's the same structure).

If it were split into two sentences, then you'd need a verb change, like *Who is which **depends** on whether...* As a single sentence, I think the part after the dash is functioning as a participle clause, where *who is which* is its subject - but I'm not strong on the terminology! But it sounds natural to me, as a native speaker.